# PHPExcel how to read cell value without interpretation?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm only reading from an Excel2007 file, not writing.

I'm looping through a RowIterator, then a CellIterator, echoing $cell->getValue() into an HTML table.  For some cells, the cell value is incorrect and appears as a number (a float, specifically) when I want the actual value (as a string).

How do I force all cell values to be the original value without conversion into numbers and without interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `getValue()` which retrieves the raw data from the cell.... that doesn't mean that it's incorrect, simply unformatted. What you're getting actually is the original value, when what you seem to want is the interpreted value. Just as an example, in MS Excel, date/time values are held as a numeric value (like a unix timestamp, except based on a different base date to unix, and as  count of days rather than seconds), and it's the application of a number format mask to that cell which is responsible for displaying it as a date.

If you want to retrieve this value with formatting applied, then there is the `getFormattedValue()` method..... assuming that you haven't loaded the file with `readDataOnly`.... which will apply the MS Excel number format mask to the cell value and returning it as displayed in MS Excel.

If you don't want formatting, but your cell contains a formula, then `getValue()` will return the formula, not the calculated value.... if you want the calculated value instead of the formula, then you use the `getCalculatedValue()` method.

All this is described in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate)

Comment: I also tried turning on and off setReadDataOnly, no effect.

Comment: The cell is formatted as "Time", and contains ":30", or ":60", or "2:30".  That must be the issue.

Comment: No, you were right and I was wrong; I had not tried setting readDataOnly to false AND using getFormattedValue().  That worked as expected.